# Make portion of UITextView undeletable

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a UITextView and need to make a specific portion un-deletable. Its the first 10 characters of the views text.

I just want it so that if the user is tapping the delete key on the keyboard it simply stops when it reaches say the 10th character in.

### Edit

Let me go into a bit more detail.

Let's say the prefix is '123456789:'. I want to be able to type anywhere after this prefix, it can't be editable at all though, so '123456789:' shouldn't not be altered at all. Fichek's answer does this perfectly, however the prefix isn't always there, so how can I detect when it isn't in the textview? I thought the if statement did this but it seems not to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sch's last edit makes a decent answer, but I want to offer a slightly more flexible approach.

You have to keep in mind the copy/paste system. User might select all the text in text field and try to paste in the entire value which might be perfectly acceptable, but `if (range.location <= 9) { return NO; }` will reject it. The way I'd do it is put together a string that would be a result of successful edit and then check if that string would start with your desired prefix.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *resultString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSLog(@"resulting string would be: %@", resultString);
    NSString *prefixString = @"blabla";
    NSRange prefixStringRange = [resultString rangeOfString:prefixString];
    if (prefixStringRange.location == 0) {
        // prefix found at the beginning of result string
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

**Edit:** if you want to check if the current string in text field starts with the prefix, you can use `rangeOfString:` the same way:

```
NSRange prefixRange = [textField.text rangeOfString:prefixString];
if (prefixRange.location == 0) {
    // prefix found at the beginning of text field
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this, but I don't know yet what the specifications are. +1 anyway :)

Comment: Could you check my edit please. Great answer, however when the prefix doesn't exist it still won't let me edit those first characters.

Comment: "however the prefix isn't always there, so how can I detect when it isn't in the textview?" Not sure I understood correctly, but you can use the same check (`rangeOfString:`) to see if the text file itself starts with the prefix.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the delegate method [`textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006897-CH3-SW6) To tell the text view whether to accept the delete or not.

As the documentation says:

> **range** : The current selection range. If the length of the range is 0, range reflects the current insertion point. **If the user presses the Delete key, the length of the range is 1 and an empty string object replaces that single character**.

**Edit**

Here is an implementation where the user can't delete the the first ten characters. But he will be able to insert characters there.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (range.length==1 && string.length == 0) {
        // Deleting text
        if (range.location <= 9) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Here is an implementation where he can't modify the first ten characters at all.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (range.location <= 9) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see that I need to stop character from range location 0 and length 10 to not be deleted but Im unsure how to actually do this. A simple example would be really appreciated, please.

Comment: If there are 20 characters, can the user delete the first character? Or he only can delete characters with index 10 or more?

Comment: Lets say the text says "123456789: This is a string of numbers." I want those first 10 character to not be deletable, so '123456789:' cannot be deleted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting a sample! I have tried your second method as I don't want those first character altered at all however  it leaves me in a state where I can't delete (great) however can't add any character either. In relation to this, how do you detect if the delete key has been tapped?

Comment: Does this happen even if the initial text has more than 10 characters? Or do you want the user to be able to add "6" if the initial text is "012345" ("012345" -> "0123456")? What about "012345" -> "0123465"?

Comment: If it has more than 9 characters then I can add and delete, however lets say I start with '123456789: boo' then I can add character and delete back to '123456789: b'. An odd predicament, I have tried adjusting the location to make up for that odd character with no luck.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand :) Can you edit your post by adding some examples and specifying the initial length of the text. I understand that when the text has more than 10 chars, you don't want the first 10 to be editable. But I don't know if the text is initially shorter than 10 chars and what to do in that case.

Comment: @JoshKahane - Sorry, didn't see your question about detecting the delete key. This is done using the condition: `if (range.length==1 && string.length == 0)`, this is what the documentation I quoted in bold says.

Answer (score 1):

for a complete solution you need to handle several cases, including the cut and paste operations that may start in the uneditable part and extend into the part which the user can edit.  I added a variable to control whether or not an operation that includes the uneditable part but extends into the editable part, is valid or not.  If valid, the range is adjusted to only affect the editable part.

```
// if a nil is returned, the change is NOT allowed
- (NSString *)allowChangesToTextView:(UITextView *)textView inRange:(NSRange)changeRange withReplacementText:(NSString *)text
                       immutableUpTo:(NSInteger)lastReadOnlyChar adjustRangeForEdits:(BOOL)adjustRangeForEdits;
{
    NSString *resultString = @"";

    NSString *currentText = textView.text;
    NSInteger textLength = [currentText length];

    // if trying to edit the first part, possibly prevent it.
    if (changeRange.location <= lastReadOnlyChar)
    {
        // handle typing or backspace in protected range.
        if (changeRange.length <= 1)
        {
            return nil;
        }

        // handle all edits solely in protected range
        if ( (changeRange.location + changeRange.length) <= lastReadOnlyChar)
        {
            return nil;
        }

        // if the user wants to completely prevent edits that extend into the
        // read only substring, return no
        if (!adjustRangeForEdits)
        {
            return nil;
        }

        // the range includes read only part but extends into editable part.
        // adjust the range so that it does not include the read only portion.

        NSInteger prevLastChar = changeRange.location + changeRange.length - 1;
        NSRange newRange =  NSMakeRange(lastReadOnlyChar +  1, prevLastChar - (lastReadOnlyChar +  1) + 1);

        resultString = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:newRange withString:text];

        return resultString;
    }

    // the range does not include the immutable part.  Make the change and return the string
    resultString = [currentText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:changeRange withString:text];
    return resultString;
}
```

and this is how it gets called from the text view delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    // did the user press enter?
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    NSInteger endOfReadOnlyText = [self.spotTextLastSet length] - 1;
    NSString *newText = [self allowChangesToTextView:textView inRange:range withReplacementText:text
                                       immutableUpTo:endOfReadOnlyText adjustRangeForEdits:YES];

    if (newText == nil)
    {
        // do not allow!
        [TipScreen showTipTitle:@"Information" message:@"The first part of the text is not editable.  Please add your comments at the end."
                      ForScreen:@"editWarning"];
        return NO;
    }

    // lets handle the edits ourselves since we got the result string.
    textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    textView.text = newText;


    // move the cursor to change range start + length of replacement text
    NSInteger newCursorPos = range.location + [text length];
    textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(newCursorPos, 0);
    textView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    return NO;
}
```